# How to change ActionBar height dynamically from fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've one Activity with multiple fragments. Most links from Navigation bar replace the fragments through transactions. The material guidelines allow you to adjust height to make space for more buttons, text.
How do I do adjust height of support ActionBar (not Toolbar) from fragment?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Change style.xml to

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:actionBarSize">70dp</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Read the question again. I asked how do I dynamically do it from fragment.